# Cantor's proof on uncountability of irrationals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, irrational-numbers

I have a question regarding Cantor's proof that the set of irrational numbers is uncountable.
As far as I know, to prove this, Cantor proves that there exists a mapping between irrationals and naturals so that at least one irrational is left out. However, the existence of such a mapping does not imply the nonexistence of a one-to-one mapping.

Did I understand the proof wrong? If yes, an explanation would be much appreciated!

Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

Comment: Cantor actually proves something different. Assume you have a bijective mapping (one to one correspondence) from N to R. He constructs an element that is not mapped to, so it wasn't really a bijection. He hasn't proved that there is a mapping that leaves out some numbers, but rather that *all* mappings leave out some numbers.

Comment: @Henry: Cantor's diagonal argument doesn't require the list to be injective; nor it requires the assumption that the list contains *all* the real numbers.

Comment: @Asaf Ah, okay. There's so many slight variants on it that are all equivalent; I've never been sure which was his original argument.

Answer (score 5):

You are mistaken. Cantor proved that given **any** function $f$ from the natural numbers to the irrationals, there is an irrational number which is not in the range of $f$. This number will be different given different functions, but this shows that there cannot be any surjecitve function from $\Bbb N$ onto $\Bbb{R\setminus Q}$.